# How to create a custom filter at .net core

Tags: filter, .net-core, model-binding

I try one of the following without any success.
1. Validate a property's (username) value in the model binding with another property's value in the model (id, to find the user).
2. Validate all the sent model to a put request in the controller.

How can i create a custom filter to catch all the model to one of the property's value by use another value in the sent model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fluent Validator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/) in .NET Core for such validations

Step 1 :- Register it in the startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddFluentValidation(fvc =>
                fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
}
```

Step 2 :-

Define the validation rules like this

```
  public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrationViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RegistrationViewModel>
   {
    readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;



        public RegistrationViewModelValidator(IUserRepository userReo)
        {
            RuleFor(reg => reg.FirstName).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(reg => reg.LastName).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(reg => reg.Email).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(reg => reg.FirstName).Must(DoesnotExist);
        }

  bool DoesnotExist(string userName)
    {
        return _userRepo.FindByUserName(userName) != null;
    }
```

}

Step 3:-

IN the controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FormValidation(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid) {
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Great!";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Refer this [link](https://fluentvalidation.net/) for the complete documentation

Comment: thanks but it is not helf. What i need is to check the sent user model the consists of user id, some other information the user name and to check if the exists username in the db of the user by the id in the model. It is a little bit more complicated from empty or not empty

Comment: @liolrn, Sure. You can check for existence of username in DB as well. For ex:- If you are using some repository classes inject that dependency to RegistrationViewModelValidator .cs and call a method in it to find out if the use exists.

Comment: @liolrn, look at the edited answer above if it helps